# not able to create database use rake db:create mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do `rake db:create` in my rails app.

I am getting below error

> Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"new-development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"password"}

I am not sure whats wrong in this.

I have `gem 'mysql2'` in my Gemfile.

I have my `database.yml` like below

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: new-development
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password: password
```

I already tried by changing the gem version to `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'`. This didn't help.

Comment: you think that'd help?

Comment: @HashRocket , well that did work but on `rails s`, I got this.
` Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)
`

Comment: Make sure that you've assign the proper username and password on your `database.yml`

Comment: this is what I have `  username: root
  password: password`

Comment: Then, try add `host: localhost` and run `rake db:create` again. This is under your `development:`. Let me know if you still have an error or it is working.

Comment: Got this

`Mysql2::Error: Can't create database 'new_development'; database exists: CREATE DATABASE `new_development` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`
`

Comment: So it already exist, drop and create again. Try to: run `rake db:drop` and after run `rake db:create`. I add the answer below, if it solves your question please accept. If there's still an issue tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the host of database is located. In your `database.yml` you should add `host: your_host`:

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: new-development
 pool: 5
 host: localhost     # <your host>
 username: root      #< your_username >
 password: password  #< your_secret_password >
```

Comment: `rake db:dropAccess denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Are you sure you supply the proper username and password?

Comment: Sometime this was happened, some developers installs not just one `mysql` in there machine. Is it only one mysql installed in your machine? If not check if the one that is running is the proper mysql.

Comment: Oops, the password supplied was incorrect in yml fine. 

But now after running migrations, I got another error 

`StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
`

Comment: Did you dropped the database and create it again?

Comment: Probably some redundant things in the db. Let me check.

Thanks though. I am not sure how this worked, I mean changing the db name did the trick for me..

Comment: Changing the name did the trick because I believe that the database you created still exists. I guess my answer helped you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assure you can connect to it via CLI. Something like

```
mysql -u <user> -p <database_name>
```